# jQuery: parent() times 3 - how to avoid stacking of parents if I don't know a selector

Tags: jquery, parent

I couldn't find a quick answer to this problem …

I'm inside a click-event and using `$(this)`

I'm trying to select an element three levels up without knowing what selector it has.

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id')
```

This works fine, but is there a better way in doing this?

Like `parent(3x)` or similar?

Comment: Minor nitpick time: Use `.prop()` not `.attr()` to get the id.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist but id is an attribute not a property, right?

Comment: @roasted - It's both, if the id attribute is used in the HTML. The id property is always present, and changes when the attribute changes. Using prop() would be faster, as it looks up the property on the element, and not the HTML attribute. As a sidenote, the answers all seem to use parents(), which could be really expensive, depending on how large the DOM is. Adding an identifier of some sorts, and using closest() would be better.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can try using [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) with [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/). eq() is zero base index so first element will have zero index and third element will have 2 index.

```
$(this).parents().eq(2).attr('id');
```

This is equal to:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
```

> The .parents() method allows us to search through the ancestors of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements ordered from immediate parent on up; the elements
>   are returned in order from the closest parent to the outer ones,
>   [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Answer (score 8):

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) like this:

```
$(this).parents().eq(2).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 7):

you can also try.

```
$(this).parents(':eq(2)');  //and then get ID
```

Comment: This way is the fastest way to get job done.
Here's the benchmark to prove it: https://jsperf.com/jquery-get-element-s-nth-parent